# Is it possible to mock a method of a class which is indirectly being called from testing class unit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

In the below code, I have a Class **Program** which have **test()** method that I want to test.

It calls class **"Iprint"** method **"printnu()"** which again calls class **"Inumber"** method **"returnn()"** as shown below:

```
public class number : Inumber
{
    public int returnn()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}

public class print : Iprint
{
    public int printnu()
    {
        Inumber test = new number();
        return (test.returnn());
    }
}

public class program
{
    public int test()
    {
        Iprint hello = new print();
        return (hello.printnu());
    }
}
```

How can  I mock **"returnn()"** method of class **number**?
Is it possible? If not any tips on how to solve this kind of problem!

I have tried

```
Mock<Inumber> mock = new Mock<Inumber>();
mock.Setup<int>(x => x.returnn()).Returns(15);

Iprint test = new print();

var a = test.printnu();

Assert.AreEqual(a, 15);
```

the mocking doesn't work and execute its own block and return 10!
I have tried setting **Returnn()** method to **virtual** and mock it, still it didn't work.

Comment: interface would need to be injected into `print` class for this to be testable in isolation. Currently you are manually creating the number class which is what is tightly coupling the `print` class

Comment: is it possible to let the ``` print``` class be tightly coupled and mock ```number``` class?

Comment: not with moq. you should try to avoid tight coupling. It is seen as a code smell and makes testing code in isolation difficult.

Comment: Got it my friend. Thanks

Comment: Also, naming conventions... It's not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are manually creating the `number` class which is what is tightly coupling the `print`

You should try to avoid tight coupling. It is seen as a code smell and makes testing code in isolation difficult

`Inumber` interface would need to be explicitly injected into `print` class

```
public class print : Iprint 
    private readonly Inumber number;

    public print(Inumber number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int printnu() {
        return number.returnn();
    }
}
```

for this to be easier to test in isolation.

```
//Arrange
var expected = 15
var mock = new Mock<Inumber>();
mock.Setup(x => x.returnn()).Returns(expected);

Iprint test = new print(mock.Object);

//Act
var actual = test.printnu();

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```